# Not able to install azure-cognitiveservices-speech using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure

Tried with the following commands,

```
pip3 install azure-cognitiveservices-speech
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
```

Error:

```
ImportError: libasound.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_speech_py_impl'
```

Comment: you're missing libasound.  not sure which distro you're using, so just use your distro package manager and install whatever package that contains libasound.

Comment: @ewong Even after installing libasound facing the same issue

Comment: @RaphaelTitus Are you still blocked here? Do you have the prerequisite libraries installed successfully? Get the prereqs for your distro here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/setup-platform?tabs=dotnet%2Cwindows%2Cjre%2Cbrowser&pivots=programming-language-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libasound package is not found in Ubuntu virtual machines and Azure functions (Linux).. We can install the package "sudo apt-get install libasound2 alsa-utils alsa-os".
For Azure functions (Linux), we can go with Docker containers where libasound can be installed in Dockerfile.